# JS: Link specified in data-href not working in carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

I have a carousel: [**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/qftcjcbp/3/). I am trying to figure out how to link each image that appears as the main image to its own page, such that:

- when I click on the image of the wagon - it goes to wagon.com,
- when I click on the image of the heirloom photo - it goes to
  heirloom.com,
- when I click on the image of the woolly - it goes to woolly.com, etc.

  ```
        <li>
                      <a href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e9/Baker's-van-r.jpg"></a>
                      <a data-href="www.wagon.com"></a>
                      <div class="block">
                         <h2>Wagon wins again</h2>
                      </div>
      </li>


      <li>
                      <a href="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/00/60/ff/0060ff20d110050c0e350c55f7c7f3be.jpg"></a>
                      <a data-href="www.heirloom.com"></a>
                      <div class="block">
                          <h2>Heirloom Scareloom</h2>                                                                 
                      </div>
      </li>

      <li>
                      <a href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/79/Mammuthus_trogontherii122DB.jpg"></a>
                     <a data-href="www.woollies.com"></a>
                      <div class="block">
                          <h2>The Original Wollies</h2><br>                                                               
                     </div>
      </li>
  ```

In the JQuery, I have made use of  `data-href`` to assign the link for each each image.

```
var imgAlt = $(this).find('img').attr("alt"); //  Get Alt Tag of Image
        var imgTitle = $(this).find('a').attr("href"); // Get Main Image URL
    var imgLink = $(this).find('a').attr("data-href"); // Get Main Image URL
        var imgDesc = $(this).find('.block').html();    //  Get HTML of block
        var imgDescHeight = $(".main_image").find('.block').height();   // Calculate height of block
```

However the links do not go to the specified page. Would appreciate any direction on how to deal with this. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Also I see a  problem in your fiddle, you are requesting the images all the time. once you have all the images why dont you reuse it.. If you open up the network tab you can see the requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok - try this - not sure if its the solution: but it seems to work in the fiddle. I would probably advise you to rethink the structure of the main image section (it seems a bit messy and confusing), but I think the issue that you are referring to the wrong "a" when setting the imgLink. It is the second (or last)  that has the data href not thefirst.

Try swapping that with this:

```
var imgLink = $(nextImage).find('a:last').attr("data-href"); // Get Main Image URL
```

That now seems to add a changing href to the images as they cycle through the sequence. also - try using the full (absolute path) for the hrefs - I just put in "http://www.heirloom.com/" and clicking the image took me there out of the fiddle page.

Comment: yes, thanks, this works. although i don't understand why the right 'a' wouldn't be picked up (without specifying :last) if attr("data-href") is being specified. also, i agree the main image section is messy, will clean that up soon.

Comment: glad to help - sorry for being a schnoob.

Comment: it's fine, all forgiven, thanks for the help. sorted out my headcloud too.

Answer (score 1):

Check this,

```
 var imgLink = $(this).find('a:last').attr("data-href"); // Get Main Image URL
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qftcjcbp/10/